# What is the best place for constants in Swift in the iOS project

Tags: swift

What is the best place for constants in Swift in the iOS project? For example, I need to create constants for the error domain name and error codes.

Should I use global constants or some class like `Constants` with static fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create new `enum` with raw values:

```
enum ErrorDomainName: String {
    case MyDomain = "MyDomain"
    case OtherDomain = "OtherDomain"
}
```

Also you can create extension with nested type. This way you put constants in scope they belong.

```
extension NSError {
    struct DomainName {
        static let MyDomain = "MyDomain"
        static let OtherDomain = "OtherDomain"
    }
}

NSError.DomainName.MyDomain
```

Comment: You can do the same for error codes. Just take a note that there could multiple error codes per domain, so you need enum or nested struct of error codes for each domain.

Comment: For now I decide to use `enum` and get the `rawValue` to construct `NSError` object. Is it ok?